# Group strings in file into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to group strings in a list into a dictionary. I read in a file to get a list of strings. I want to take that list and group all of the items by their id.

This is what the file (logtest.txt) contains...

```
Id: 1

FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out
Done

Return Code: 0

Id: 2

FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out
Done

Return Code: 0

Id: 3

FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out
Done

Return Code: 0
```

So far I read all of the lines in the file into a list. I want to then take those strings and group them by the `id` numbers into a dictionary where the key is the `id` number and the values are all of the string from `Id: 1` to the next string that contains `Id:`.

```
def getAllTheLinesInLogFile():
    f = open('logtest.txt', 'r')
    return f.readlines()

def getDictOfItems(allLinesInFile):
    dict = {}
    # ???
    # items = allLinesInFile.groupby()
    for item in items:
        print("{0}".format(item))
    return dict

logFile = open('logtest.txt', 'w+')

allLinesInLogFile = getAllTheLinesInLogFile()
dictOfItems = getDictOfItems(allLinesInLogFile)
for item in dictOfItems:
    print(item.key)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group the sections delimiting by `Id:`:

```
from itertools import groupby
with open("in.txt") as f:
    d = {}
    groups = groupby(f, lambda x: x.startswith("Id:"))
    for k, v in groups:
        if k: # if we have a line with "Id:.."
            # use the line as the key
            k = next(v).rstrip() 
            # call next on the grouper object extracting 
            # the second item which is our section of lines
            d[k] = list(map(str.rstrip, next(groups)[1]))
```

Input:

```
Id: 1
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out
Done
Return Code: 0
Id: 2
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out
Done
Return Code: 0
Id: 3
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out
Done
Return Code: 0
```

Output:

```
  from pprint import pprint as pp
  {'Id: 1': ['FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out',
       'Done',
       'Return Code: 0'],
 'Id: 2': ['FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out',
       'Done',
       'Return Code: 0'],
 'Id: 3': ['FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out',
       'Done',
       'Return Code: 0']}
```

If your data actually has multiple empty lines the code will still work, if you don't want the empty lines you can filter them. If you want to keep the newlines just remove the `str.rstrip` calls.

If you are planning on overwriting the file after doing some work then writing to a tempfile as you go might be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear what you're asking, but maybe this will help:

```
with open('logtest.txt', 'r') as logFile:
    id_ = None
    dictOfItems = {}
    lines = []

    for line in logFile:
        if line.startswith("Id: "):
            if id_ is not None:
                dictOfItems[id_] = lines
                lines = []
            id_ = int(line[4:])
        else:
            lines.append(line)

for key, item in dictOfItems.items():
    print(key, item)
```